# Dataframe partial string search

Tags: dataframe

I have a dataframe with a column 'A' containing filenames (filename and extension).  For example: xyz.pdf

I would like to search and locate rows based on the filename without the extension pattern. Something like the following:

```
filename = 'xyz'
df[df['A'].str.contains(fileName, na=False)]
```

the problem with the above is that it will also find rows whose A column is xyz123.pdf.

How can I only locate the row which has exact match 'xyz' and not xyz123?

Comment: Such as `df[df['A'] == filename]`?

Comment: yes, except I would like to match df['A'] containing value 'xyz.pdf' with my search pattern of 'xyz'.